# 'fprintf' Color Format Wrapper

Tags: c++, colors, formatting, wrapper, printf

Is it possible to make a wrapper function where I can pass the last two arguments of `fprintf` such as `_Format` and `...` and it do something like the following:

```
void Log::green(_Format, ...[args])
{
    // Set to green
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    // Print
    fprintf(stdout, _Format, args);
    // Set back to default color
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_GREEN);
}
```

Comment: you can for example use the [rlutil](https://github.com/tapio/rlutil) header only library, and yes, there's no need to use `fprintf` in your case, just use the safer `cout` stream.

Comment: Does `SetConsoleTextAttribute` flush the output before setting attributes? If not, you should manually flush the output before calling it, otherwise the wrong text may end up with your selected color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use the `vfprintf` version of `printf` and initialize `args` using `va_start`/`va_end` like this:

```
void Log::green(const char * format, ...) 
{ 
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);

  // Set to green 
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                           FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
  // Print
  vfprintf(stdout, format, args);
  // Set back to default color
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                          FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_GREEN);
  va_end (args);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, since you're using C++, you should be using `cout` instead of `fprintf(stdout, ...)`.

Second, you can use functions like this one:

```
inline std::ostream& green(std::ostream &s)
{
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, 
              FOREGROUND_GREEN|FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    return s;
}
```

to allow you to write code like this:

```
cout << "Switching to green color... " << green << "Now, I'm green!"
```

You can find a complete library of functions here: [Add color to your std::cout](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16431/Add-color-to-your-std-cout)

Comment: I prefer `fprintf` over `cout` why "should" I be using it instead?

Comment: It's not worth getting into an argument over coding style on this site. Many people find code using `cout` to be more readable. If you're not one of those people, and you're not working with any of those people, feel free to use `fprintf`. It will work just fine.